# Как получить запрос от клиента на стороне сервера vds Ubuntu при помощи python?

Tags: python, ubuntu, vds, client

В общем, мне нужно узнать, как получить запрос от клиента на стороне сервера vds при помощи python и отправить ответ.
Запрос может быть любой, GET, POST и тп.
Допустим, цепь начинается со строчки кода python на стороне клиента:
`r = requests.get(url)`

Comment: погуглите fastapi

Comment: ну или банально `Flask`

Comment: CGI ещё никто не советовал? Есть ещё aiohttp, tornado, django